# Best architectural choice for communication b/w a web client and a TCP server via relay

Tags: web-services, networking, web, architecture

Hi, I am a little confused in finalizing the software architecture of 1 of the projects I am planning to build. The solution is something like-

- There are 2 devices in separate home network(private addresses) A and B. A acts as the data source and provides access to the data source over TCP to authenticated users. B is used by the user to fetch the data from A via a web browser. Authentication is something which is not the problem at hand now.
- There is a central server S with a public IP address, which acts as a relay b/w A and B. S hosts a web application over a web server accessed by B. When the browser requests for the data, web app needs to fetch this data from device A.
- There is an application on the same server S which has a TCP connection established with device A. So basically for web app to get the data one of the approach is to request it from  this application which in turn fetches it from A. For this I can have a web service exposed from this application which can fetch the data.
- First question - Is this approach good enough? or is there a better alternative
- Second - As the application with TCP connection might want to talk to device A for updates  or other things, I want a thread of execution running in this application which runs parallely to the context of web service, meaning when web app calls the web service, it will perform the job and also might want to do something on its own without being triggered by the web app.

I might have missed something basic as I am new to web services